# Angularjs: how to "rerun" $formatters when some setting is changed?

Tags: angularjs

A date format setting is in the scope.

It is used by filters to display dates in label and by a directive putting a function in **$formatters** from **ngModel** to format date in input.

When the format setting in the scope changes, the date displayed through the filters is refreshed by angular.

But not the input fields through $formatters.

The only way to force this refreshed we have found is to set all fields to null, then in $timeout to reset them to the value to display to force the reexecution of the $formatters.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

**Answer:**

By merging answer from Sergey Moiseev and answer to 11380866, I was able to add a satisfying solution to the directive.

Store the settings in rootscope (as it is used from lot of directive in solated scope) and react to it by the generic code:

```
$rootScope.$watch('userSettings.dateFormat.fmt', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
                if (newVal != oldVal) {
                    var viewValue = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
                    for (var i in ngModelCtrl.$formatters) {
                        viewValue = ngModelCtrl.$formatters[i](viewValue);
                    }
                    ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = viewValue;
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
            });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your code? It's pretty hard to figure out what you're doing without it.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3407

Comment: Great it is that. Note that your fiddle works by adding this code to your watch:`code`var viewValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
                for (var i in ctrl.$formatters) {
                    viewValue = ngModel.$formatters[i](viewValue);
                }
                ngModel.$viewValue = viewValue;
                ngModel.$render();